# .NET C# DateTimeFormat.LongTimeFormat does not react to changes in the Region dialog in Control Panel

Tags: c#, .net, cultureinfo

I am getting different results from running C# code on two different Windows Server 2016 machines.

The code is running in a Windows Service using .Net Framework 4.7.2.

I am using this code:

```
var cinfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
```

and then examining the value of:

```
cinfo.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern
```

What I find is:

On machine 1, the value of `cinfo.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern`, as I would expect, agrees with the Long Time pattern selected in the Region dialog on Control Panel.

On machine 2, the value of `cinfo.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern` seems unaffected by the Long Time pattern in the Region dialog on Control Panel and instead is always set to `"h:mm:ss tt"`

I checked that `cinfo.UseUserOverride` is set to true on both machines and also checked that, when changing the value in the Region dialog, the culture mentioned in the Region dialog is English (United States).

Can anyone explain why the machines might behave differently?

Thanks

Comment: What is the expected format? Can you share examples of expected and actual values? Are both the servers running in the same timezone?

Comment: Thanks for the question. Yes, both servers are in the same timezone (US Central) and both are, according to IT, identically set up. What I am finding is that if I choose "HH:mm:ss" as the "Long time" in the Region dialog in Control Panel, then after I restart my Windows Service, I see the LongTimeFormat change to exactly that string. On the other machine, it does not change at all and stubbornly remains as "h:mm:ss tt" which I believe is the default for the en-US culture. My expectation is that the LongTImeFormat should match what's entered in the "Long time" field in Region in Control Panel